# Mysql alias called in subquery working only in production server

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    items.id AS item_id,
                (SELECT max_all
                    FROM items_sales
                    WHERE itemID = item_id LIMIT 1) AS max_all
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN items_sales ON items_sales.id = orders.item_salesID
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = items_sales.itemID
```

This query is working on my production server, but not on my local machine.

I'm getting `Unknown column 'item_id' in 'where clause'`

The item_id alias, is not recognised in the subquery.

MySQL version on local machine is: 5.7.10 while the production one is 5.1.73.

Comment: Presumably this query returns lots of NULLs ?!?! If we understood what you were trying to do, we could probably help you write a better query.

Comment: I cut the query a bit, just to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Does it work if you use the original "items.id" in the sub-query?
Aside: There's been a lot of debate about using plurals for table names. Singular is generally preferred.

Comment: Yes it's working with 'items.id'.
I have inherited of this DB with all the weird things (Id's name and plural => singular)...